# Upload video to YouTube by my mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, upload, youtube

I would like to allow admins of my page to upload video on single YouTube account. I find a kind of solution, but I have a problem. I've already got ClientID, ClientSecret and RefreshToken. Unfortunately, I got stuck. There is an error, wchich says

```
'BuildService' does not exist in the current context
```

although I have installed YouTube Data API v3 from nuget. Does anyone have any similiar problem? Is it any simplest way to make uploading possible?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: Yes, my fault. I typed asp, but it correct it to asp-classic and I didn't notice this change.